# How to chain linux commands together using a python script

Tags: python, linux, subsystem

I want to write a python script that will automatically write these commands into the Linux terminal.

```
nc -C smtp.google.com 25
HELO google.com
```

Comment: Um, unless I'm missing something; [don't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html).

Comment: What's with the [tag:subsystem] tag? Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux? That has its own tag, [tag:wsl].

Comment: Take a look at python's pexpect module.

Comment: If all you want to do is execute commands, then you most likely want to use a shell script.